# Multiple imputation chained equation followed by PCA

Tags: pca, stata, mice

I've performed multiple imputation chained equations to address missing data but I would like to perform PCA to obtain a SES index for which one of the variables I had missing data (MAR). Could anyone suggest how I may go about this in Stata since the mi estimate: command does not seem to accomodate this.

Comment: Questions about how to do "x" with software "Z" are often considered off-topic here, but maybe you could change your question to "How to perform & pool PCA results after using a multiple imputation technique to replace missing values (is it possible?)?" I'd be really interested in that question anyway, but I expect there might be difficulties with pooling a data-driven latent factor based on the different data within each imputation set. I do not know enough of PCA to provide an answer of my own, but I hope this helps refine your question.

Comment: Ask on statalist.org, you may have better luck with that. As the author of `polychoric`, which you undoubtedly stumbled upon, I recommend different methods that I outlined in https://ideas.repec.org/p/boc/scon16/15.html.